# how to add remove from cart button in virtuemart 2.04 shopping cart module

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using Virtuemart 2.04 shopping cart module for JOOMLA 2.5.1.

I want to add remove from cart button in the shopping cart module for each product.

So anybody can give idea to add this feature in my cart module..??

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you'd like to remove the add to cart button in the product list view. (but keep it when you are in the detailed view)
Therefore you have to go to the virtuemart administration
then to configuration,
then click on the 'site' tab,
then in the right column named layout click on configuration under 'select the theme for your shop' and finally check no for 'Show the Add-to-cart Button on the product list?'

Hope this helps